# opencv C++ neural network predict() function throws "Bad argument" error

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network

I have managed to train a neural network to recognize numbers in an image and have saved the network parameters to an .xml file.

However, when testing the network against a new image the code fails at the predict() stage with the error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Both input and output must be floating-point matrices of the same type and have the same number of rows) in CvANN_MLP::predict, file ........\opencv\modules\ml\src\ann_mlp.cpp, line 279.

ann_mlp.cpp line 279 is:

```
if( !CV_IS_MAT(_inputs) || !CV_IS_MAT(_outputs) ||
    !CV_ARE_TYPES_EQ(_inputs,_outputs) ||
    (CV_MAT_TYPE(_inputs->type) != CV_32FC1 &&
    CV_MAT_TYPE(_inputs->type) != CV_64FC1) ||
    _inputs->rows != _outputs->rows )
    CV_Error( CV_StsBadArg, "Both input and output must be floating-point matrices "
                            "of the same type and have the same number of rows" );
```

I have checked input rows by running this code:

```
cv::Size s = newVec.size();
    int rows = s.height;
    int cols = s.width;
    cout << "newVec dimensions: " << rows << " x " << cols << endl;
```

...and it comes out with the expected 1 x 900 vector / matrix.

I have set the input and output matrices to be CV_32FC1 as per the error dialog like this:

Input matrix

```
cv::Mat newVec(1, 900, CV_32FC1);
    newVec = crop_img.reshape(0, 1); //reshape / unroll image to vector
    CvMat n = newVec;
    newVec = cv::Mat(&n);
```

Output matrix

```
    cv::Mat classOut = cvCreateMatHeader(1, CLASSES, CV_32FC1);
```

And I try to run the prediction function like this:

```
CvANN_MLP* nnetwork = new CvANN_MLP;
nnetwork->load("nnetwork.xml", "nnetwork");

int maxIndex = 0;
cv::Mat classOut = cvCreateMatHeader(1, CLASSES, CV_32FC1);

//prediction
nnetwork->predict(newVec, classOut);
    float value;
    float maxValue = classOut.at<float>(0, 0);
    for (int index = 1; index<CLASSES; index++)
    {
        value = classOut.at<float>(0, index);
        if (value>maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = value;
            maxIndex = index;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated...

Comment: Quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370807/using-artificial-neural-network-in-opencv-specifically-c/29385619, but different input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is your input, not your output.

First it's important to understand that OpenCV deserves a lot of the blame for this, not you. Their C++ API is quite mediocre, and it caused major confusion to you.

See, normally in C++ when you define a 1x900 matrix of floats, it *stays* a matrix of floats. C++ has strong type safety.

OpenCV does not. If you assign a matrix of bytes to a matrix of floats, the latter will change its type (!).
Your code initializes `newVec` to such a matrix of floats, then assigns a second matrix, and then yet another matrix. I suspect that `crop_img` is still an image, i.e. 8 bits. Reshaping it will make it 1x900, but not floating point. That's the job of `.convertTo`.

Comment: Yep - spot on. Good work Msalters. Added crop_img.convertTo(crop_img2, CV_32FC1); to the beginning of the reshape process and solved the problem. Thanks for taking the time.